# How to set the image taken/picked to the uiimage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am successful at taking or picking a photo and uploading to Firebase Storage but I am not sure how to set that pic to the UIImage, see code:

UIImage that needs the photo to be set to:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPhoto: UIImageView!
```

How to select or take a photo:

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add a Photo", message: "Choose From", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        self.imagePicked = sender.tag // new
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    let photosLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photos Library", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.imagePicked = sender.tag // new
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    let savedPhotosAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Saved Photos Album", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        self.imagePicked = sender.tag // new
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(photosLibraryAction)
    alertController.addAction(savedPhotosAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How do I set the photo I just selected or took to myPhoto?

Comment: Set the image picker's delegate to `self` and implement `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected or captured image from
 UIImagePickerControllerDelegate function. You must need to set
 delegate of your UIImagePickerController(picker) instance.

Asking for permission

The app must ask for permission from the user before accessing the
 camera/ the saved photos.The app should display a message to the user
 explaining why it needs the camera or photo library access. You can
 set this message by setting the NSCameraUsageDescription and
 NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key in the Info.plist file of your app.

This will work for the sure

```
imagePicker.delegate = self


extension StackOverflowViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController( picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        var selectedImage: UIImage?
        if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = editedImage
            self.imgView.image = selectedImage!
        } else if let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = originalImage
            self.imgView.image = selectedImage!
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel( picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            // Further logic to perform 
        }
    }
}
```

You can review all other related to UIImagePickerController from this
 official reference link.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey/1619164-originalimage